# "Bad Request" message from Import Schema of Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, dynamics-business-central

I have to migrate data from CRM Business Central into an Azure SQL database. The source data comes from REST API. I created a linked service related to it. Then I created a copy activity with the following:

[image]

[image]

The preview works. I get data in a JSON format. For the mapping tab, I tried to import the schema and set the field "value" as an array. I got the following result:

[image]

However, on the right side of the mapping, I can only see "@odata.context" proposed as a "sink mapping". I overwrote it by writing the right fields. When I run the pipeline with "debug mode", the pipeline is not triggered and I received a "Bad Request":

[image]

The error comes from the mapping. My question is: how does the "Import schema" work in case of JSON data? Do I have to import manually the schema?

Comment: A bad request must come from the REST API side. So something is not right when your calling your REST API

Comment: I don't think it's link to it because the preview works and the connection to the REST API linked service too. When I don't specify the mapping, the pipeline runs well. In this case, the array field is not migrated. That's why I stated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the sink column `@odata.context` to other name by excluding the special characters.

I have reproed with a sample rest API and got the same error when I used the special characters (@, .) in the sink column `ex :@data.id`.

[image]

I have changed the sink column name `ex: data_id` to exclude special characters and the pipeline ran successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thanks to your answer, I noticed that the mapping pointed 2 source fields output to the same sink field. I tried with special characters, it's still working.